# How to get google translate to work only for one particular control and not the entire page?

Tags: asp.net, google-translate

I am trying to use google translate in my website to translate the text in a label from English to Hindi.To start off, I have used the following code which actually works for the entire page:

```
<head>
<meta name="google-translate-customization" 
content="3280487709591956-dc3fc45d489f056a-g5378ebab0cbcd0a4-12"/>   
</head>
```

This is where I have added the google translate element:

```
<div id="google_translate_element">            
<table>
<tr><td></td></tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Code for a label and a dropdownlist, this is inside the table tag:

```
<tr>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 244px">
            <asp:Label ID="lblSubjectArea" runat="server" Text="Subject Area" 
              meta:resourcekey="lblSubjectAreaResource1"></asp:Label>

        </td>
        <td style="width: 537px">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSubjectArea" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"  Height="20px"
                OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlSubjectArea_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="160px" 
                meta:resourcekey="ddlSubjectAreaResource1">
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 376px">
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit()
{
    new google.translate.TranslateElement({ pageLanguage: 'en', 
    layout:google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE }
    ,'google_translate_element');
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" 
src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js? cb=googleTranslateElementInit">
</script>
```

Now, when I select the language say Hindi, what happens is that, the entire website text including the text in labels,dropdownlists etc. gets translated, but I want the translation to be limited to just one label not the entire page.What should be done ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, found the solution.I found this in the google translate help.Here I am pasting a part of what I read :

Preventing translation of your webpages

If you're a webmaster and would prefer your web page not be translated by Google Translate, just insert the following meta tag into your HTML file:

```
< meta name="google" value="notranslate">
```

If you don't mind your web page being translated by Google Translate, except for a particular section (like an email address, for example), just add class=notranslate to any HTML element to prevent that element from being translated. For example:

```
Email us at <span class="notranslate"> sales at example dot com
```

So if there is a control whose text I don't want to translate,I simply add class="notranslate" in it's tag.In the code in my question above if I want the label to be unaffected by the translation, I would rewrite the code as:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblSubjectArea" runat="server" Text="Subject Area" 
          meta:resourcekey="lblSubjectAreaResource1" class="notranslate"></asp:Label>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function googleTranslateElementInit()
    {
        new google.translate.TranslateElement({ pageLanguage: 'en', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.HORIZONTAL, multilanguagePage: true }, 'google_translate_element');
    }
```

**Notes:**-

Take Div in Given Id = "google_translate_element" ,

This Code is put on Your Masterpage Or Web Page in Header.